# Using probabilistic method to show size of bipartite subgraph

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be simple undirected graph with max degree $\Delta(G)=9$.
I need to show there's a bipartite subgraph of size at least $\frac{5}{9}|E|$.
I can easily show that by randomly coloring each vertice with one of two colors (each with equal probability) and keeping only edges whose ends are in different colors that the expected size of such graph is $\frac{1}{2}|E|$, but how can I leverage the fact about the degree to my advantage?
Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing it right now, but usually degree information is best captured using the [local lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_local_lemma).  I'm not sure if that can be used here somehow though.